# Convert Excel Table Layout to WEBI Table

Tags: excel, webi

I've been provided with a large complex table in excel and need to add two additional columns to the end in WEBI.
For the purpose of automation I've been tasked to re-create the table in WEBI before adding on the calculated fields from the data warehouse.

So far i've attempted to import the excel file into Webi, While this re-created the table as in excel perfectly, i am unable to add different formulas on each individual row as the table is built from objects rather than being in plain text cells.

Is there way to import the layout and contents of a table in excel as plain text rather than objects?

Comment: EVERYTHING in BusinessObjects is an object. So the short answer to your question is "No." Can you describe more about what you are trying to do? Can you add screenshot to your question of what you are looking to achieve?